# Charge Density Of A Conducting Strip

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, mathematical-physics

I am currently doing a project which requires me to figure out the charge density of a strip. Assume that the strip is isolated in a vacuum.

Assume the strip is 1 dimensional, kind of like a rod. What would the function of charge density of the strip be? (The function is f(x) and depends only on 1 variable as it is assumed to be 1 dimensional)

How about if we assume that the strip is 2 dimensional? What would the 2 dimensional function of charge density of the strip be? (The function is f(x, y) and depends on 2 variables as it is assumed to be 2 dimensional)

If you have any books or research papers on the subject could you please also post them. If my question is unclear please feel free to ask for more information. Thanks

Comment: in order to find the charge density, you must know something about the strip, e.g. has it been given a uniform charge, is it in an external electric field, is it a conductor, dielectric? It is also worth noting that a two-dimensional object can have a charge density that depends on no spatial parameters, one parameter or two parameters, it all depends on the conditions the object is subjected to.